# Can this method for unit testing a stored procedure be improved?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, testing

When I have written unit tests for my stored procedures, they usually look something like this:

```
/* Unit test for stored procedure which runs a query */

/* Define #temp table with structure of query results */

/* Define and set variables for stored procedure parameters */ 

/* If stored procedure queries from a particular table...*/ 

/* Truncate table and populate with sample data */ 

/* Call stored procedure using variables but insert results into table */ 

/* INSERT #temp EXEC usp_TestProc @P1=1, @P2 = 'X' */

/* Query #temp table to confirm that all fields have certain values */

/* Query #temp table to confirm that certain number of rows exist */ 

/* If results are incorrect, display error message */
```

While this will work, it feels clunky somehow and is very difficult to maintain over the course of a long-term project where the requirements are constantly changing.

1. Is there a better way (or standard way) to test a stored procedure
   like this?
2. Is the difficulty of maintenance simply part of the job and worth
   the effort in order to have the unit tests? I have to say that at
   most of my jobs, the DBAs rarely do unit testing in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have written a series of blogs on [unit testing select stored procedures](http://dbtestunit.wordpress.com/category/stored-procedure/select-sproc/) using [DBTestUnit](http://dbtestunit.wordpress.com/) that might be of use.

Comment: Do you mind summarizing the essence of your solution here? Link-only answers are generally better posted as comments.

Answer (score 2):

Use, for example, [TST - TSQL Test Tool](http://tst.codeplex.com/). It will automate your process. See other solutions I asked on [sqa](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/803/database-code-unit-testing-tips)

Luck.

Answer (score 2):

I have been doing unit testing T-SQL for more than four years so far.
I think it much easier to use C#, which is more versatile. For example, in C# I have no problem unit testing a stored procedure that returns two or more result sets - it is plain impossible if you use T-SQL. I described the process [in this article](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/close-those-loopholes-lessons-learned-from-unit-testing-t-sql/) and in this [blog post](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2010/10/15/benefit-from-unit-testing-t-sql-speed-up-your-test-harness.aspx).